Find minimum number of nodes to be removed so that each node has atmost one adjacent node in a graph (not necessarily a DAG)
I have directed graph G (not necessarily a DAG). I need to formulate an algorithm returning the minimum number of nodes that need to be removed, such that each node has at most one adjacent node.
Any idea on which algorithm to use or how to proceed further? I'm completely stuck on this.
Tried finding articulation points to approach this, but it fails when there's a cycle in the graph.
Thinking about using some version of Min Cut Algorithm, but stuck on it as well.
